# Using downloadable themes for android app

Tags: android, themes

I am developing my first app and wanted to add a downloadable themes feature. Initially I thought of downloading my themes through my app itself like Swiftkey. But after reading the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031769/create-downloadable-custom-theme-and-apply-it-during-run-time), it seems it would be a bit difficult to implement. So, I decided to implement it like Rocket Player, using different apks to be downloaded from the play store.

Can someone guide me as to the method to implement it?

Thanks!

EDIT : After roaming around the internet I have found that I can pass data using AIDL. I have managed to implement AIDL as an example. But I am able to return only primitive types. I wanted to return Theme object but I don't think it is parcelable. What options do I have for sending a Theme object from a service to an activity?